# Warning after upgrading to xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1 Used As Name of the previous parameter rather than as part of selector

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6, ios6.1

its not an error it only warning

Example:-

in .h file

```
-(void)updateFromTable:(NSManagedObject*)mObject:(NSString *)key:(NSString *)value;
```

'mObject'Used As Name of the previous parameter rather than as part of selector

.m file

```
-(void)updateFromTable:(NSManagedObject*)mObject:(NSString *)key:(NSString *)value{

    [mObject setValue:value forKey:key];
    [self save];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the warnings such as *Parse issue: 'aVariable' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector* you get while compiling you should use:

in .h-file:

```
-(void)updateFromTable:(NSManagedObject*)mObject key:(NSString *)key values:(NSString *)value;
```

and in you .m-file:

```
-(void)updateFromTable:(NSManagedObject*)mObject key:(NSString *)key values:(NSString *)value
{
// your cool code goes here!
}
```

and You should use:

```
[self updateFromTable:myObject key:myKeyString values:myStringWithValues];
```

or for better clarity:

```
[self updateFromTable:myObject 
                  key:myKeyString
                values:myStringWithValues];
```